# Read the Response and stored to database using Microsoft SMO (Server Management Objects)

Tags: vb.net, smo

Im trying to call to an URL
And than i will get response into XML format and based what Response i will get it will create `Tables` successfully into database using `Microsoft SMO (Server Management Objects)` which Allowing me to create and generate databases and tables. but for some reason it coludnt insert any data to tables and they are `NULL` 
Screenshot

[image]

XML:

```
<ICECAT-interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://data.icecat.biz/xsd/files.index.xsd">
     <files.index Generated="20200219011050">
    <file path="export/freexml.int/EN/1424.xml" Product_ID="1424" Updated="20200218012414" Quality="ICECAT" Supplier_id="1" Prod_ID="C4811A" Catid="846" On_Market="1" Model_Name="11" Product_View="513730" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/1424_6912543175.jpg" HighPicSize="2478427" HighPicWidth="2598" HighPicHeight="3276" Date_Added="20051023000000" Limited="No" >
        <M_Prod_ID Supplier_id="11" Supplier_name="Cisco">C4811A</M_Prod_ID>
        <M_Prod_ID>Tempcomp3109</M_Prod_ID>
<Country_Markets>
  <Country_Market Value="NL"/>
  <Country_Market Value="BE"/>
  <Country_Market Value="FR"/>
  <Country_Market Value="UA"/>
  <Country_Market Value="GB"/>
  <Country_Market Value="DE"/>
  <Country_Market Value="BG"/>
</Country_Markets>
    </file>
    </files.index>
    </ICECAT-interface>
```

Module:

```
Class Module1
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim url As String = "http://data.Icecat.biz/export/freexml/EN/daily.index.xml"
        ProcessXMLFeedURL(url)

    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ProcessXMLFeedURL(MyURL As String) As Boolean

        Dim OK As Boolean = False

        Try

            Dim rssReq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(MyURL)

            Dim username As String = ""

            Dim password As String = ""

            Dim encoded As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password))

            rssReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded)

            '//Get the WebResponse

            Dim rep As WebResponse = rssReq.GetResponse()

            '//Read the Response in a XMLTextReader

            Dim xtr As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(rep.GetResponseStream())

            '// Set up the connection to the SQL server

            Dim MyConnectionString As String = "Data Source=......"

            Dim Connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MyConnectionString)

            Dim MyServer As Server = New Server(New ServerConnection(Connection))

            Dim db As Database = New Database(MyServer, "xxxxx")

            db.Create()

            '//Create a new DataSet

            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

            '//Read the Response into the DataSet

            ds.ReadXml(xtr)

            '// Parse tables

            For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables.Count - 1

                Dim Mytable As Table

                Dim MyTableName As String = ds.Tables(i).TableName

                If Not HaveTable(MyConnectionString, MyTableName) Then

                    '// Create the table

                    Try

                        Mytable = New Table(db, MyTableName)

                    Catch ex As Exception

                        Dim ii As Integer = 0

                    End Try

                    '// Create the columns

                    Dim Mycolumn As Column = New Column()

                    For Each dc As DataColumn In ds.Tables(i).Columns

                        Mycolumn = New Column(Mytable, dc.ColumnName)

                        Mycolumn.DataType = getdatatype(dc.DataType.ToString)

                        Mytable.Columns.Add(Mycolumn)

                    Next

                    Mytable.Create()

                    Dim PrimaryKeys() As DataColumn = ds.Tables(i).PrimaryKey

                    Dim PrimaryKey As DataColumn

                    For Each PrimaryKey In PrimaryKeys

                        Dim Myindex As Index = New Index(Mytable, PrimaryKey.ColumnName)

                        Myindex.IndexKeyType = IndexKeyType.DriPrimaryKey

                        Myindex.IndexedColumns.Add(New IndexedColumn(Myindex, PrimaryKey.ColumnName))

                        Mytable.Indexes.Add(Myindex)

                    Next

                End If

                Using MyConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MyConnectionString)

                    MyConnection.Open()

                    Using bulkcopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(MyConnection)

                        bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "[" & MyTableName & "]"

                        Try

                            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(ds.Tables(i))

                        Catch ex As Exception

                            Dim iw As Integer = 0

                        End Try

                    End Using

                    MyConnection.Close()

                End Using

            Next

        Catch ex As Exception

            Throw ex '// Do errorhanddling here

        End Try

        Return OK

    End Function

    Shared Function getdatatype(Mydatatype As String) As DataType

        Dim dty As DataType = Nothing

        Select Case Mydatatype

            Case Is = "System.Decimal"

                dty = DataType.Decimal(2, 18)

            Case Is = "System.String"

                dty = DataType.VarChar(500)

            Case Is = "System.Int32"

                dty = DataType.Int

        End Select

        Return dty

    End Function

    Shared Function HaveTable(MyConnectionString As String, TableName As String) As Boolean

        Dim OK As Boolean = False

        Try

            Dim dbConn As New SqlConnection(MyConnectionString)

            dbConn.Open()

            Dim restrictions(3) As String

            restrictions(2) = TableName

            Dim dbTbl As DataTable = dbConn.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)

            If dbTbl.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                OK = True

            End If

            dbTbl.Dispose()

            dbConn.Close()

            dbConn.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception

            Dim ss As Integer = 0

        End Try

        Return OK

    End Function

End Class
```

Can anyone please help me!

Comment: First: you have try/catch blocks where you seem to catch an exception and then ignore it. That strategy will make it VERY difficult to debug or support this code. Next: how much of this code is working? It sounds like maybe the part that creates the tables in your DB is working, and the problem only happens when you try to insert the data. Is that correct?

Comment: @tgolisch yes it is correct :) code is workin and tables and columns with also be created in database , the only part i had issue with is inserting the data while is tryin create tables and columns.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the `catch` block, near `bulkcopy.WriteToServer`, are you getting any errors?

Comment: @tgolisch yup :) Cannot access destination table

Comment: Sounds like you have your solution then?

Comment: @tgolisch Yes , thanks for help :)